# Min. Character Count Plugin for textarea like the one in this site?

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

i am searching for a jQuery Plugin which should validate the textarea to the min. character with the count. like the one they are using in this site.

any idea about the existing plugin?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for that. Here's what you could do if you have jQuery included, at a minimum:

```
<form action="action.php" method ="post" onsubmit="check(100)">
    <textarea id="txt" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check!" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function check(min) {
        if(strlen($('#txt').val()) < minimum) {
            alert('You need to have more than '+min+' characters to submit!');
            return false;
        }  else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if you need more clarifications or if this isn't what you expected.

**EDIT**

```
if(strlen($('#txt').val()) < minimum) {
```

is actually:

```
if(($('#txt').val()).length < minimum)) {
```

Got JS mixed up with PHP there :)